# Python script throwing segmentation fallout error in google compute engine

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I am trying to extract data from BigQuery and load it into Cloud Storage Buckets using Cloud Dataflow. I have a .py script that does the same.

The below query runs absolutely fine with no errors

```
SELECT DISTINCT local_event_start_date \
                            FROM `{src_proj}.{src_dataset}.{src_table}` a, \
                            ( SELECT MAX(audit_timestamp_asve) max_adsmart, \
                                MAX(audit_timestamp_lsve) max_linear \
                                FROM `{src_proj}.{src_dataset}.{src_table}` \
                            ) b \
                            WHERE a.audit_timestamp_asve=b.max_adsmart \
                            or a.audit_timestamp_lsve=b.max_linear order by 1 desc;""".format(
            src_proj=self.config.bq_source_project,
            src_dataset=self.config.bq_source_dataset,
            src_table=self.config.bq_source_table
        )
```

The moment I tweak the above query in order to test for a single local_event_start_date(partitioned column) the script throws either "Killed" or "Segmentation fallout" error

```
"""SELECT local_event_start_date \
                            FROM `{src_proj}.{src_dataset}.{src_table}` \
                            WHERE local_event_start_date = '2019-04-28';""".format(
            src_proj=self.config.bq_source_project,
            src_dataset=self.config.bq_source_dataset,
            src_table=self.config.bq_source_table)
```

My VM is a F1 Micro instance with 1.70GB RAM. Is this the problem, do I need to upgrade to n1-standard-1 with 3.75GB

I am just running a .py script on VM instance and thats it.

Comment: If you're running out of memory the syslog should tell you about it - look for messages about the OOM killer being active in `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `DISTINCT` on top there in this second query?

Comment: have you tried following this documentation   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Comment: Hi there I am a member of the Google Cloud Platform support team. The troubleshooting required here needs information like your project id, and things you should not expose on Stackoverflow... I would suggest for this issue you open a support case with Google directly... Follow the instructions contained here.........       ..Even if you are only using the free trial tier you can open a ticket ........  https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en